# pytorch dataloader default_collate argument use with to(device)

Tags: pytorch, batch-processing, data-stream, dataloader

Ive been trying to integrate the to(device) inside my dataloader using to(device) as seen in https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/11372

I defined it on FashionMNIST in the following way:

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
batch_size = 32
trainset = datasets.FashionMNIST('~/.pytorch/F_MNIST_data/',
                                 download=True,
                                 train=True,
                                 transform=transforms.ToTensor())
rain_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, collate_fn=lambda x: default_collate(x).to(device))
```

But i get the following error:
**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to'**
It seems that the output of default collate is a list of length 2 with the first element being the image tensor and the second the labels tensor (since its the output of next(iter(train_loader)) with collate_fn=None), so I tried with the following defined function:

```
def to_device_list(l, device):
    return [l[0].to(device), l[1].to(device)]
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, collate_fn=lambda x: to_device_list(x, device))
```

And I got the following error:
**AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to'**

Any help please on how to do it?

Comment: I know its too late, but added the solution

Answer (score 2):

The fashion mnist dataset returns a tuple of `img` and `target`, where the `img` is tensor and target is `int` value for class.

Now, your `dataloader` takes batch size samples from `dataset` class to get list of samples. Note, this list of samples is now, `List[Tuple[Tensor, int]]`(using typing annotation here). Then it calls, collate function to convert `List[Tuple[Tensor, int]]` into `List[Tensor]`, where this list has 2 tensors. The first tensor is stacked array of images of size [32, 1, 28, 28], where 32 was batch size and second tensor is tensor array of int values(class labels).

The `default_collate` function, just converts array of structures to structures of array.

Now, when you use `collate_fn=lambda x: default_collate(x).to(device)`, notice that default_collate returns you a list of tensors. So calling `.to` on list wont work and should be called on all elements of the list.

**Solution**
Use

```
collate_fn=lambda x: list(map(lambda x: x.to(device), default_collate(x))))
```

The map function transfers each element of list(from `default_collate`) to cuda, and finally, call list, since `map` is evaluated lazy in python3.

Comment: For anyone facing this issue, I would recommend to use debugging tool in pycharm or other ide, or just pudb. Its very easy to pinpoint the issue that way.